# How to change "data" value in viewmodel from store listener?

Tags: extjs, listener, bind, viewmodel

I binded a placeHolder in 'selectfield' like this:

```
{
xtype           : 'selectfield',
bind        : {
    store       : '{chapters}',
    placeHolder : '{chapterPlaceHolder}'
    }
}
```

Now i want to change the data of 'chapterPlaceHolder' in the ViewModel from store listener:

```
Ext.define('SomeViewModel', {
extend      : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

data        : {
    chapterPlaceHolder  : null
},
stores      : {
    chapters        : {
        model   : 'model.SiteChapter',
        listeners: {
            datachanged: function() { how to change the 'chapterPlaceHolder' in data? }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Hope i was clear enoght...

Comment: Which Ext version?

Comment: Its 6.0.1 version...

Answer (score 2):

Define the event handler on a [view controller](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html). View controllers provide a method, [getViewModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-getViewModel), to access the view model. The controller should be configured on the same class as the view model. This example assumes that is the select field.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.app.ViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.FiddleViewModel',
    data: {
        chapterPlaceHolder: null
    },
    stores : {
        chapters: {
            listeners: {
                datachanged: 'dataChangedHandler'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.app.ViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.FiddleViewController',

    dataChangedHandler: function(store, eOpts) {
        this.getViewModel.set('chapterPlaceHolder', ...);
    }
});

{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    bind: {
        store       : '{chapters}',
        placeHolder : '{chapterPlaceHolder}'
    },
    controller: 'FiddleViewController',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'FiddleViewModel'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get [`viewmodel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) inside of [`datachanged`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.data.AbstractStore.html#event-datachanged) event. After getting `viewmodel` you can use [`get`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-get) or [`set`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-set) to change value of any field inside of view-model.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cof)** , I have created a demo using your code and put my efforts in same code. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('SomeViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: "viewmodel.demoVM",
            data: {
                chapterPlaceHolder: null
            },
            stores: {
                chapters: {
                    listeners: {
                        datachanged: function () {
                            var vm = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myform')[0].getViewModel();
                            vm.set('chapterPlaceHolder', 'data changed event called......');
                            //how to change the 'chapterPlaceHolder' in data ?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            itemId: 'myform',
            fullscreen: true,
            viewModel: {
                type: 'demoVM'
            },
            defaults: {
                margin: 20
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    autoSelect: false,
                    bind: {
                        store: '{chapters}',
                        placeHolder: '{chapterPlaceHolder}'
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Load Data In store ',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var vm = btn.up('formpanel').getViewModel();
                    vm.get('chapters').loadData([{
                        text: 'First Option',
                        value: 'first'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Second Option',
                        value: 'second'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Third Option',
                        value: 'third'
                    }]);

                    //You can also set like below
                    //vm.set('chapterPlaceHolder', 'Data loaded on button click......');
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But now the view wont load my store after i added: viewModel: {
        type: 'working-schedule'
    } to my Panel...

Comment: And i am very surprised that Ext didnt do a simmple way to change the data from the model handler...what are alternatives of this?To put a function in controller?

Comment: If you want to load store then then you need to put proxy and autoLoad property for that

Comment: Or another way you can create painted event of your view inside of controller and in that method you can get store using view model. After getting store you can load here.